# Drupal 7- blocks assigned to custom regions are randomly unassigned

Tags: drupal-7

I set up a number of custom regions for my home page, which uses a custom template, and was able to position them and assign blocks to them as I wanted.

However, at random, any blocks I assign to these regions will disappear. When I look in the `_block` table of the database, the value set to the region field is -1 (ie., not assigned), and I have to go in and reassign the blocks for these regions.

This happens whether I cache my blocks or not.

It does not happen when I run a cron or clear my cache. As this only happens to my custom fields, I feel like there is something else I should be doing in addition to setting up my regions in the theme's and subtheme's `.info` files, that would make block assignments to these regions as persistent as they would be to a standard region.

A number of people have reported this over at Drupal.org, but no one has been able to come up with an answer. I've researched this for the last several weeks, and looked through any scripts that might store or rewrite my database to those values.

It always happens overnight, but not at any reliable interval: I can go a week without it happening, or I can go a day.

It does not happen on the offline XAMPP stack I use as my development server. There may be something going on with my web host, but as this is a very specific problem, I am thinking it has to do with how my custom regions are set up.

I used the directions at this blog: http://megadrupal.com/blog/add-new-regions-in-drupal-7-themes.

I have posted a question about it there, but have not received a reply yet.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I have about 25 sub-theme and randomly blocks in random sub-themes is being unassigned.

Comment: I think I may have found a solution, for the short term, but it's not an optimal one. I turned off my daily cron and disabled caching of my site. This validates my suspicion that there is a caching issue in relation to the new custom regions. However, this has some serious drawbacks in performance and automated site maintenance. It also makes me wonder even more where this is coming from, since when I run a cron manually and clear the cache manually, I don't lose my blocks. So why is it only when this is reset automatically, in the middle of the night?

Comment: I have exactly same issue, blocks are being unassigned during cron job.

Comment: OK, if you are finding it with your cron, too, I'm going to go and examine the cron scripts being run. I'll report back when I've done so.

Comment: Max, I know this has been a long time ago, but did you find a solution?